# Regular Expression to find date format after underscore and a period

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of files with some being backups, I need to ignore the backups formatted
.2018-12-22 or _2019-12-18.
I believe Regex would be my best option but have little experience.

I have tried using regex but cant seem to get the format to accept the period or underscore before the date after the file name.

```
file_list=(glob.glob("/home/test/testdir"))
date1=
date2=
backups=[date1, date2]

for file in listoffiles:
    exists = os.path.isfile(file)
    if exists:
        for i in backups:
            ignore = i in file
```

The files should be ignored if the backup files are there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```py
import re 

backups=["2018-12-22", "_2018-12-23", "2019/23/14", ".2019-23-14", "2019-12-23"]
ignore_regex = re.compile(r"[_|.]\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}")

for i in backups:
    ignore = True if ignore_regex.match(i) else False
    print(i, ignore)
```

Results :

```py
2018-12-22 False
_2018-12-23 True
2019/23/14 False
.2019-23-14 True
2019-12-23 False
```

## Edit 1

```py
ignore_regex = re.compile(r"auto[_|.]\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}")
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for! I have a question though, if I had other extensions to deal with like .bak or .old could I loop through those as well as the ignore_regex to check for duplicate files?

Comment: Could you please add more details, your said extension : do you mean "date.back" like this ?

Comment: Yes my apologies, some of the files will have a format like this: auto.misc, auto.bak, auto.2019-02-25, or auto_2019-02-25 for example. The only file that should not be ignored out of that sample would be auto.misc

Comment: @WillMccurry my awser is updated, tell me if it's work for you. Feel free to validate the awnser by clicking on the check button.

Answer (score 1):

`re.search` is the way to go. Let's try with two examples:

```
import re
string1 = 'abc.2018-12-22 ghi'
string2 = ' or _2019-12-18.2929'

re.search('(\.|_)(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})', string1).group(2)
re.search('(\.|_)(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})', string2).group(2)
```

#### Output:

```
'2018-12-22'
'2019-12-18'
```

#### Explanation:

`re.search` looks for match groups that you can then extract. Each group is encased in parentheses. Let's decompose the regular expression `(\.|_)(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})`:

`(\.|_)`: Find a `.` or a `_` character. (`\` is a escape character, it lets you use `.` as a character instead of its regex meaning). This is group 1.

`(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})`: Afterwards, find 4 numbers, a dash, 2 numbers, a dash and 2 numbers. Because it is also encased in parentheses this is group 2 and your group of interest, and that's why we add `group(2)` to `re.search`.